# How do I get the values of y_true and y_pred in the confusion matrix?

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification, weka

I am using the weka program and i want to know the values of y_true and y_pred through confusion matrix that appeared in the classification results , because I want to calculate the balanced multiclass accuracy value .

Answer (score 1):

https://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/
The screencap in the `Evaluate predictive accuracy` of `Machine Learning without Programming` shows the `Correctly Classified Instances` and the corresponding percentage.